# is there software for jar file copy protection, or licensing software

Tags: copy-protection

is there good copy protection mechanism to protect my jar file from being copied DVD or  is there licensing which can limit number of machine installation.

I have software which i require to distribute on DVd. i want my client to just run the application in machine.

advance thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Copy protection can't prevent your file to be copied but you can make it fail when it is run on unlicensed machines. Selection of a copy protection mechanism is a matter of budget and time. There are many companies with many products.

You can go with not yet cracked technologies like iLok etc. This is applicable for very high revenue cases. But if your target audience is less than 1000 people then a simple in-house solution might work. Consequence of a complex method is typically many calls to support line and unhappy customers.

Things got a lot easier after clients are all connected to internet. You can make some simple parts to run on server which a cracker would never dive into for a replacement. Or the app might download the contents from server after installation. Latter is what I did for my app and I never had any problems.